# How to debug Visual Studio .NET application under Mono in Linux?

Tags: c#, linux, visual-studio-2012, mono

I'm trying to debug an application built in Visual Studio C# under MonoDevelop in Linux.

I have the source code, so I followed instructions that appears at Icaza's blog at http://tirania.org/blog/archive/2010/Feb-20.html without success (which basically consists on create an empty solution and set the Execute command to the already compiled application)

The application is executing correctly but when I load the source code file, and set a breakpoint, it never stops.
pdb's were also transformed to mdb's using pdb2mdb command.

What am I missing?

BTW, load source code into Monodevelop and build the application under Linux is not an option right now, due to the big size of the application and lots of tweaks in the build process. Just wanted to debug the compiled assembly.

Comment: You want to debug from command line? first you need to recompile it, before starting to debug.

Comment: @jaumaff Did you find any solution yet?

Answer (score 0):

There is a command line utility for [soft debugger](https://github.com/mono/sdb), have a look it, this might be what you are looking for.