# Using RemoteDebugger to debug C# mono program on Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: c#, visual-studio, mono, visual-studio-2015, raspberry-pi3

I'm trying to debug my C#-mono program on a Pi 3 using the latest MonoRemoteDebugger (1.0.10).

The program compiles on both the build machine (a windows 10 64 bit laptop) as well as on the target (Pi 3). The binary also runs on the target machine.

But when i try to remote debug using Visual studio 2015 Community with the MonoRemoteDebug extention it fails.

- The debug server that runs on the target machine is found by the extention client.
- When i select the server and press connect then it connects.
- But when it tries to start the binary it fails, it returns with the message that the .exe cannot be found.
- It seems that is tries to find it in the directory of the development machine (C:\users\user\projects\project\Program.exe).

I have followed this tutorial:
https://mmkaram.wordpress.com/2015/04/18/run-and-debug-c-net-on-a-raspberry-pi/
 and also read the following post [Mono remote debugging from Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23108728/mono-remote-debugging-from-visual-studio#)

But i can't seem to get it to work, can anyone help me?

Comment: Well today i tried several version of MonoDebugger 1.04 till current release. All give the same result als in the post description. Hope that someone can shine some light on this problem.

Comment: Nobody any idea? Does somebody have it working on A rasberry pi 3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you to use Xamarin Studio.
Remote-Debugging from Windows to Linux (for me on a Beaglebone) works without any problems.

https://store.xamarin.com/account/my/subscription/downloads#all-versions
https://eladnava.com/debug-remote-mono-apps-via-xamarin-studio/

I also tried to get the debugging running from within VS. It is "possible", but only very basic and awkward to use.

Xamarin Studio is also free and fully compatible to the VS Solutions. So if you want you can use VS to write your code and then load the solution in Xamarin Studio to do your debugging.