# How to remotely debug Mono ASP.NET app from Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, mono, remote-debugging

I want to make in Visual Studio 2017 a web server for Raspberry Pi, using ASP.NET (Mono framework). I have previously developed a console app and used MonoRemoteDebugger. If possible, I want to do this for the web server. I could use Xamarin Studio 6.3, but I am interested in Visual Studio.

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23108728/mono-remote-debugging-from-visual-studio) describes how to remotely debug Mono from Visual Studio, but the solutions are not for ASP.Net/Mono apps.

Is it possible to remotely deploy and debug a web server (Mono) on Linux/Raspbian from my Windows PC (Visual Studio)?

Comment: Although it doesn't directly answer your question, you can write and debug your project from Visual studio 2017 and then just deploy it on the the Pi.  I have done exactly that for my current project.  You will need to create a .net core web site project.  My Pi comes with .net core 2.0 onboard, so that is my target, but I presume you can deploy an older version if required.

Comment: @Neil Is it possible with Mono? Should I install .NET Core Runtime on Raspbian, and also, how do you deploy it (can you detail or recommend a tutorial)?

Comment: There are lots of articles on publishing dotnet core applications. When I run 'dotnet publish -r centos.7.x64' I end up with a folder that contains all the files needed for my application, which I copy to the target.  I've had to install the dotnet core runtime for the version I'm using too, but that was all that was required.